# wxPython TreeCtrl - Dragging multiple items

Tags: drag-and-drop, wxpython

Dragging multiple items in wx.TreeCtrl does not seem to work. I'm trying to use this example https://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDropWithFolderMovingAndRearranging with the tree set to wx.TR_MULTIPLE. Even if multiple items are selected, only one gets dragged.

In the TODO list at the top, it says

> add support for multiple selection / moving multiple items (should be easy)

What would be the best way to implement this so that it works for multiple items exactly the same way as for a single item?

Comment: Maybe [wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.html) supports this (it is part of wxPython)

Comment: I tried customtreectrl and got the same result. Only one item could be dragged at a time.